# How to SELECT one column and yield two different columns based on distinct WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL (*PostgreSQL* in that case) and can't figure out how to apply two distinct conditions to the same row in order to return two different rows. It's probably because I can't name what I'm trying to do that I can't find answers, I guess...

An example: Given this data,

*table_clothes*

```
user_id | clothes | is_blue
---------------------------
   1    |  skirt  |  t 
   2    | t-shirt |  f
   3    |  socks  |  t
```

I would like to be able to select:

1/ the count of distinct clothing item that is blue and wore by each user

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT clothes) AS nb_blue_clothes
FROM table_clothes
WHERE is_blue
GROUP_BY user_id;
```

2/ the count of distinct clothing item worn by humans

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT clothes) AS nb_clothes
FROM table_clothes
GROUP_BY user_id;
```

Is there a way to join this two SELECT into one query that would yield something like:

```
user_id | nb_blue_clothes | nb_clothes
--------------------------------------
   1    |       45        |     67
   2    |       4         |     48
   3    |       89        |     103
```

Any idea what I should learn about in order to solve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am a little bit irritated: 1 is an orc, not an human. Why does it got a count?

Comment: Thanks @S-Man I forgot to delete that part of my example that was proven irrelevant to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to somehow apply a condition before counting. You could use an explicit `case` expression like @fa06 suggested, or you could let PostgreSQL do the heavy lifting for you and use a `filter` clause:

```
SELECT   user_id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT clothes) FILTER (WHERE is_blue) AS nb_blue_clothes,
         COUNT(DISTINCT clothes) AS nb_clothes
FROM     table_clothes
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below - using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT case when is_blue then clothes end) AS nb_blue_clothes,
    COUNT(DISTINCT clothes) as nb_clothes
FROM table_clothes
GROUP_BY user_id
```